# How can I solve FIREBASE UNIQUE ID problem

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

Hey there how can I change that unique number system, I just wanna use simple 1,2,3...

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igu8P.png)

Comment: Using sequential numeric keys is an anti-pattern when it comes to Firebase. See [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

Answer (score 0):

As @FrankvanPuffelen already mentioned in his comment, storing consecutive numbers as keys in the Realtime Database can be considered an anti-pattern. Why? Because it cannot scale.

But what does 1, 2, 3... actually mean? It means that you are trying to store data in an array. If you have an object that needs a few items stored in an array, it's not a problem but if you create a node with a large number of elements, you might get into problems at a larger scale.

So I recommend you go ahead with what you already have. Use those pushed IDs and everything will work perfectly fine.